# google-services.json is missing

Tags: android, build.gradle, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am tired to find what is the actual problem in my code.I am trying to use FCM in my android project.I followed step by step procedure given in firebase console to activate services in my project, but i encountered a problem like `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
>      Searched Location: 
>     C:\Users\rossh\AndroidStudioProjects\Register3\app\src\debug\google-services.json
>     C:\Users\rossh\AndroidStudioProjects\Register3\app\google-services.json'

If i create new project , i worked fine but same thing didnot work in my old project,though i include same command in both `build.gradle` file of project.

Here is my build.gradle for app-level

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.rossh.register"
    minSdkVersion 13
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
   dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
 }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and buile.gradle for project-level

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to            all sub-projects/modules.

  buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'



        }
      }

    allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
    } 

     task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
```

Comment: In which folder did you put the google-services.json file?

Comment: i put it in root-level folder of my project. Inside  ../project_name/app

Answer (score 1):

I see no problems in your gradle files. It may not work if your old project is using and older gradle version. So please update the things I guess. 
The error you are saying is about google-services.json file is missing. Have you created this file. 
Please cross check the process of generating google-services.json file.

Source: **[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/)**

Comment: thanks at all but things in my gradle all upto date.I am not using ang older library . i hope i will fixe it soon .and i want to thank you for your tutorial simplifiedcoding.com. :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally i get the solution.Two things that slove my problem are

1.update sdk for google repository

2.include following dependencies
`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'`

in build.gradle